# Print duplex Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

```
worksheet.PrintOutEx(1,2, 1, false, Type.Missing, false, false, Type.Missing);
```

I am using this code to print successfully.

I want to do duplex printing but I don't know. Any direction on this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the [PrinterSettings.Duplex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.duplex(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

You can use the [CanDuplex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.canduplex(v=vs.100).aspx) property to check to see if the printer supports duplex printing.

OR

You can try like this..

[How to set duplex printing for Microsoft Word Automation clients in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2012/05/19/how-to-set-duplex-printing-for-microsoft-word-automation-clients-in-c-vb-net.aspx)

```
MyDuplexSettings.DuplexSettings ds = new MyDuplexSettings.DuplexSettings();

short status = 0;
string errorMessage = string.Empty;
status = ds.GetPrinterDuplex("<<Printer Name>>", out errorMessage);

if (status == 0)
{
//Console.WriteLine("Error occured. Error Message is : " + errorMessage);
//Some error occured, errorMessage is available in string errorMessage
}
else
{
 //Console.WriteLine("Current Duplex Setting is : " & status);
 //Call successfull, Current duplex flag is set to status
}

status = 2; //set duplex flag to 2
ds.SetPrinterDuplex("<<Printer Name>>", status, out errorMessage);
```